# Getting the logged in user when a program is executed as Administrator

Tags: c#, windows-installer

When my program installs using msiexec.exe it adds a task to the task scheduler to check if it's running and start up if it's not (it's a kiosk scenario).

```
        WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        string user = windowsIdentity.Name
```

Unfortunately my task is being added as `SYSTEM` which when run won't be able to access the UserEnvironment. Does anyone know of a way to get the user who originiated the command rather than the user msiexec.exe is running as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need check it during installation process - you can use custom action on VBScript, for example, which checks logged users with help of WMI.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objReg, objWMI, colSessions

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") 

Set colSessions = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType = 2 Or LogonType = 10") 
If colSessions.Count <> 0 Then 
    'Some users are logged into Windows.
    'For example set property 
    'Session.Property("SOMEONELOGGED") = "1"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Igor - very novel solution.